# amazon rds postgres iops limit

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon RDS for postgres and want to make sure I have something right, If I use amazon rds for postgres then the maximum iops that I can get is 30,000 (queries per second) iops such as what is stated on this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html .**My question is there anyway to get above that or is that the absolute maximum ?** I am working on an application that can receive up to 55,000 queries per second during peak times and trying to see if Amazon rds could be a good fit...

Comment: queries do not neseserely generate IOPS. 55K queries can generate as little as no input output operatio per second

Comment: btw I think 55K queries per second means it is time to scale your application to several databases on some classifier or optimyzing your application code to reduce number of queries

Comment: Yes you are correct we will have it spread out to different databases.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS RDS for Postgres yes 30,000 is the max limit that you can achieve using RDS Instances. But if you launch your Postgres on a I2 EC2 instance you can achieve your required IOPS check this documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/i2-instances.html